# SSRS is not making change in Font Size

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I am using below HTML to generate a SSRS report and giving the same as a default parameter.
The html view is coming perfect as per the tags however it is not changing the font size of the given string.

I am using this inside a textbox control.

Can any one suggest what to do to achieve this ?

My World

My name is Chris. RICI®EnhancedSMChris™Chris™RICI®Kumarr©

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the font size and specify in units supported by SSRS. Something like **20pt** instead of **20**.

I took sample of your code and updated the font size and tested. It works.

```
<P STYLE="font-family:Times New Roman;font-size:20pt;margin:0 0 0 0;">
      <SPAN STYLE="font-family:Arial MT Std;font-weight:bold;color:#5381AC;">My World</SPAN>
 </P>
 <P STYLE="font-family:Times New Roman;font-size:6pt;margin:14 0 14 0;">
        <SPAN STYLE="font-family:Arial;font-weight:bold;">
          <SPAN>My name is Chris. RICI®</SPAN>
        </SPAN>
 </P>
```

Per this technet article  [Importing HTML into Report](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff519562%28v=sql.110%29.aspx)
-->
"font-size: Only valid RDL size values, in absolute CSS length units are supported. **Supported units are: in, cm, mm, pt, pc**."